How to reset Week Number when the Year changes in Google Sheets
I use the following formula to determine the week number for a given period. Is it possible to reset the week number when the year changes?
=INDEX(IFNA(TEXT(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>" ")),SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))}, 2, 0), "0")))



Is there a reason for avoiding the built in WEEKNUM function? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949

You current formula not giving week number but a sequential number. If periods are not sorted as ascending, the formula will fail. How week number can be 1 for date 29-Dec-2022?

Roger, you are right. I was overthinking this. Harun, you are also right. I had to sort the periods for this to work. That was the problem, I needed that date to be the last week of 2022, not the first.

try:
=INDEX(WEEKNUM(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A3, " - ", ),,1)))



I'm getting WeekNum 2 instead of 1 for 06-Jan-22 - 12-Jan-22 period. What would be the reason for this?
You can check it here:
[link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c8wolRVwYsLcpi0xqq2XUdNxSeA4jqC0kEwiGASxeeI/edit?usp=sharing)

@ThousandSteps try: =INDEX(ISOWEEKNUM(INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A5, " - ", ),,1)))
